# Accessing project properties from an external msbuild targets file

Tags: msbuild, typescript, msbuild-task

I have a common `compile.targets` file that is used to build many different solutions. In that file I would like to check if any of the contained projects are using TypeScript, and if they are, verify that certain properties are set in those projects (i.e. `TypeScriptNoImplicitAny`). I currently build the solution like so:

```
  <Target Name="my-compile-target">
    <MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionFile.FullPath)"/>
  </Target>
```

What I would like is to be able to create a task that is run for each `.csproj` in the solution, that has access to all the properties set in the `.csproj`.

Is this possible? One workaround I *tried* was using the `BeforeTargets` attribute along with the targets I know are used to compile TypeScript:

```
<Target Name="check-typescript-options" BeforeTargets="CompileTypeScript;CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig">
    <Message Condition="'$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)' != ''" Text="Tools Version is $(TypeScriptToolsVersion)"></Message>
    <Message Condition="'$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)' == ''" Text="No tools version found"></Message>
</Target>
```

Unfortunately, MSBuild gives me a warning that those TypeScript targets do not exist, and thus `check-typescript-options` is ignored.

Comment: To figure out properties from an msbuild file, you'll either have to import it, or have your target called from within the file (i.e. have your file imported in the other file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you need to "run" in the context of the individual csproj files. To do this, given your setup I would set one of two properties

**CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets** or **CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets**

The easiest way would be to set these like so

```
<Target Name="my-compile-target">
    <MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionFile.FullPath)"
             Properties="CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets=$(PathToCustomTargetProj);"  />
</Target>
```

In this case you would have **$(PathToCustomTargetProj)** set to some file path which has targets which run within the csproj pipeline. You could set this to **compile.targets** and then your **check-typescript-options** will be called as the **BeforeTargets** will be evaluated and satisfied correctly.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Thanks!